# MySQL type conversion while ignoring nonnumeric characters

Tags: mysql, sql

How do I convert from varchar(500) to float in MySQL while ignoring non-numeric characters? My code currently looks like this

```
select distinct(customer_id), cast(val_amt as float) from(
select prsn_real_gid, vital_nam, vital_performed_date,
case when val_amt ~'^[0-9]+' then val_amt else null end as val_amt from my_table);
```

but I get the following error message

```
[Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: Invalid digit, Value 'X', Pos 2, Type: Double 
Details: 
 -----------------------------------------------
  error:  Invalid digit, Value 'X', Pos 2, Type: Double 
  code:      1207
  context:   1.XYXY04
  query:     4147
  location:  :0
  process:   query0_118_4147 [pid=0]
  -----------------------------------------------;
1 statement failed.
```

My data for example looks like this:

```
customer_id  |  val_amt
111  | 23.45
112  | 21
113  | x
114  | /
115  | 
116  | 23/24
```

As you can see I have decimals, integers, letters, symbols and nulls. I want to ignore everything that's not a decimal or integer.

Comment: You mean to get the output only numbers and decimal correct? What MySQL version are you using? Might be able to achieve that using `REGEXP_REPLACE`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `regexp`:

```
select customer_id, val_amt + 0
from my_table
where val_amt regexp '^[0-9]+[.]?[0-9]*';
```

Comment: Replaced regex with ~ and it worked, but I still do not have val_amt as a float and it still gives me a similar error to the first when I try to cast as a float.

Comment: @brightman1309 . . . MySQL supports `regexp`, not `~`:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/pattern-matching.html (and https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=78564dedcdbc62ad58e495768d18bfcc).